# how to set input box text in the google search box?

Tags: jquery, firefox, google-chrome-extension

The google search page has the following code, why the assignment below does not work? I test it via firefox extension.

```
$(".gLFyf.gsfi").val("12345");
```

input class="gLFyf gsfi" maxlength="2048" name="q" type="text" jsaction="paste:puy29d" aria-autocomplete="both" aria-haspopup="false" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" role="combobox" spellcheck="false" title="Search" value="banana" aria-label="Search"

https://www.google.com/search?q=banana&rlz=1C1CHMO_enHK655HK656&oq=banana&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.956j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: You may be running this code in the wrong context. Only a content script can access the web page contents. Or maybe the page resets the input after your code runs so you may need to wait for 'load' event on 'window' explicitly or even add a setTimeout.

Comment: thank for your reply. I just start learning the extensions and not even have included the jquery library in the test page. I will test it again once I have more knowledge about the extensions. Thanks.